# Append target="_blank" to file URLs

Tags: php

I have a bunch of HTML code. Within this code, there's some links. I want the file links to get `target="_blank` appended. This could be the HTML:

```
<p>
    A whale is a big animal. <a href="http://www.example.com/">Here is the proof.</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/whale.jpeg">Also, here's a picture</a>
</p>
```

How do I find and append to only the `.jpeg` URL using PHP?

Comment: You don't append it to the URL, you set it as an attribute of the "a" tag. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure how you create the example html but if you have your url in a variable you could do the following in php:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="<?php echo strpos($url, '.jpeg') !== FALSE ? '_blank' : '_self'; ?>"></a>
```

**EDIT**

Since you have no influence of the html that gets created, this should help:

```
$html = preg_replace('/\.jpeg\"/', '.jpeg" target="_blank"', $html);
```

Where `$html` contains the html-output from your cms.

*If you want to support more then one file-ending use this:*

```
$extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png');
$html = preg_replace('/(\.(' . implode('|', $extensions) . '))"/', '.jpeg" target="_blank"', $html);
```

Comment: The HTML I posted is pulled from a CMS database, so I can't do it like that

Comment: So how exactly do you want to alter the html?

Comment: The HTML is in a string variable, so perhaps some regular expressions. If I could answer how to do it, I wouldn't have asked